# How to properly change a resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, localization, resourcedictionary

I am working on localizing a GUI in WPF. The code that I post here will be from a prototype because I am trying to make this question as simple as possible.

I am using Resource Dictionaries to set the content of the strings in my window. I have two of them, one is German, and the other is English.

German Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- The name of this ResourceDictionary. Should not be localized. -->
    <sys:String x:Key="ResourceDictionaryName" Localization.Comments="$Content(DoNotLocalize)">Loc-de-DE</sys:String>

    <!--- Button -->
    <sys:String x:Key="MainButton_Title">Hallo Welt!</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="EnglishButton">Englisch</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="GermanButton">Deutsch</sys:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

English Resource Dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <!-- The name of this ResourceDictionary. Should not be localized. -->
    <sys:String x:Key="ResourceDictionaryName" Localization.Comments="$Content(DoNotLocalize)">Loc-en-US</sys:String>

    <!--- Buttons -->
    <sys:String x:Key="MainButton_Title">Hello World!</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="EnglishButton">English</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="GermanButton">German</sys:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also have dynamically set the content of my buttons in the XAML window:

```
<Button Content="{DynamicResource MainButton_Title}" Margin="59,68,0,80" Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="152" />
<Button Content="{DynamicResource EnglishButton}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,83,87,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
<Button Content="{DynamicResource GermanButton}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,87,90" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" />
```

I want the language to change to English when I click the English button, and change to German when I click the German button. I have gotten this far, but what I don't know is the actual code that would be needed to tell the program to change it's Resource Dictionary. I'm guessing this would go in code-behind under the two button's click events, and might also have some code in the XAML window.

These are the resources that I've used, but I am posting this question because the end solution is not clear enough to me:

-http://www.wpfsharp.com/2012/01/27/how-to-change-language-at-run-time-in-wpf-with-loadable-resource-dictionaries-and-dynamicresource-binding/

-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613547.aspx

-http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create new resource dictionary and after that you should merge with current dictionary:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri("..\\Languages\\EnglishLang.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```

If you want change language to German you should change file name in the second line.

In my example your resource dictionary should be in Languages folder.

Check my answer in this question:

[How to start an internationalized WPF-Project in SharpDevelop 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914581/how-to-start-an-internationalized-wpf-project-in-sharpdevelop-4-2/13922005#13922005)

Comment: Oh, it's glorious.... I figured it out. Thank you for your help, I have been struggling with this since yesterday morning!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Wpf Localize Extension](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/documentation) which support language change at runtime

Answer (score 1):

Add resource dictionaries to App.xaml.
On button click set

```
    ResourceDictionary _objRD = new ResourceDictionary();
    _objRD.Source = new Uri("Your Resource Dictionary Path", UriKind.Relative);
    App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] = _objRD;
```

I would recommend localization using RESX file.

Comment: What would my resource dictionary path be if it's just in the App.xaml file, like you said? I've tried localizing with RESX files, but I don't know how to change resource files at run time using a button click event.

Comment: Initially you would add default language dictionary in App.xaml and then on button click you will replace that dictionary with your desired language dictionary. So let say you put language resource dictionaries in Resource folder, then path would be
    new Uri("Resources/German.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

Comment: That makes sense. The code above goes in the button click event?

Comment: To implement using RESX files, let say you want to implement two languages English and French. So add two resx files named as Resources.resx(default english) and Resources.fr-FR.resx. Then add your resources(language specific words) in these files.

Then in XAML add the namespace
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:YourProjectName.Properties"

    <TextBlock Text="{x:Static properties:Resources.YourResourceName}"></TextBlock>

Comment: I've done that, but that doesn't support run time changes to the language.

Comment: Yes that would be executed in button click event.

Comment: YourProjectName.Properties.Resources.Culture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
I missed that, you need to set the culture whenever you want to change the language.

Comment: Do you have to refresh the window after that because it doesn't seem to realize any change?

Comment: No it should refresh data itself.

Comment: I get an "IOException was unhandled" run time error when I click one of the language buttons when using this solution. The error occurs on this line: `_objRD.Source = new Uri("C:\\Users...\\Languages\\LocalizationDictionary.en-US.xaml", UriKind.Relative);`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
        ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
        dict.Source = new Uri("Lang.pl-PL.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0] = dict;
```