# ResourceDictionary dynamic updating not updating UI in Hybrid Winforms/WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have an older Winforms application where I now use WPF for all the new content (hosted in an `ElementHost`)

I wish to change the styles (for theming) at runtime.

I have the following resource dictionary which I include in my views.

```
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">    
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/NightTheme.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Eg in one of my views (UserControl) I will have the following...

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
          <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../AppStyles.xaml"/>
          </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

I also have the following code that I call to swap the exiting (eg `NightTheme.xaml`) with another...

```
    public static void ChangeTheme(AppTheme theme)
    {
      try
      {
        if (theme == m_currentTheme)
        {     
          return;
        }

        ResourceDictionary appStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
        appStyles.Source = new Uri("/MyApp.UserInterface.WPF;component/AppStyles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        appStyles.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
        
        ResourceDictionary newTheme = new ResourceDictionary();
        newTheme.Source = new Uri(string.Format("/MyApp.UserInterface.WPF;component/Themes/{0}Theme.xaml", theme.ToString()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        appStyles.MergedDictionaries.Add(newTheme);        

        m_currentTheme = theme;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        TraceError(ex.ToString());        
      }
    }
```

I can see all the dictionaries loading, and I can see that the new merged dictionary contains the new values, however, none of the UI updates.

I even tried changing one of the elements to be a DynamicResource, ie

`<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource CommandBarBackgroundColour}">`

but this made no different either.

Other places I read say that removing and then adding a new `ResourceDictionary` to a `MergedDictionaries` as I have above should update the UI (even from StaticResources), but in my case it just does not.

Why does this not work, and what I can do to update my themes?

Comment: Do you actually assign your new, merged dictionary to your UserControl.Resources anywhere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17553157/891715

Comment: @Arie - no I don't. I was hoping I would not have to do with every single userControI we will have. I was hoping each UserControl can just include the single `/AppStyles.xaml` and that updating it's merged dictionary would trigger the UI to reload it. Perhaps this isn't the case?

Comment: Is your question implying it works for WPF but not Winforms? If it works for [WPF](https://imgur.com/oCYbDXB) then it should work for [Winforms](https://imgur.com/Hk0pl5A) as well.  There may be more than one way of doing it. We believe you'll still need a view model doing the property changed notifications for you.

Comment: The difference in Winforms (hosting WPF), is I don't have an `app.xaml` I can use as the "root host" for my resources (where apparently changing a merged dictionary is picked up)

Comment: It depends on how you organize your project. A WPF control library in this case is your friend, no `App.xaml` required even for the WPF app. Can you please clarify if this is working only for WPF and not for Winforms, or vice-versa, or neither one? You should first get it working in WPF, THEN concern yourself with hosting it in Winforms.

Comment: I didn't initially add it, but the WPF stuff is in a separate `Class Library` `<OutputType>library</OutputType>` .Does that help me?

Comment: Anything you want to re-use between winforms and wpf, not only helps you but also that's what makes sense to be in its own library, given that you intend to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the dictionary to SOMETHING, be it your global Application resources or your current view's resources. Right now your style is just floating around in the memory, doing nothing. You'll have to at least do this (if the style is global):

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myNewResourceDict);
```

or better yet:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(newTheme);
```

Also, you'll have to remove your previous dictionary from `Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` using either `Clear`, `Remove` or `RemoveAt`.

What you do right now is both a bit too much and not enough:

```
public static void ChangeTheme(AppTheme theme)
{
  try
  {
    if (theme == m_currentTheme)
    {     
      return;
    }

    // A brand new dictionary object is created here. 
    // It's not assigned to anything yet.
    // If you want to swith RD in your global App resources, 
    // creating a new dictionary is not necessary at all, 
    // you may just use Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries instead
    ResourceDictionary appStyles = new ResourceDictionary();
    // you load the contents of the xml file. Still not assigned to anything
    appStyles.Source = new Uri("/MyApp.UserInterface.WPF;component/AppStyles.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    // the theme loaded from the xml is removed from the dictionary
    appStyles.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

    ResourceDictionary newTheme = new ResourceDictionary();
    newTheme.Source = new Uri(string.Format("/MyApp.UserInterface.WPF;component/Themes/{0}Theme.xaml", theme.ToString()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

    // new theme is added to the dictionary. 
    // The dictionary itself is still not assigned to anything...
    appStyles.MergedDictionaries.Add(newTheme);        

    m_currentTheme = theme;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    TraceError(ex.ToString());        
  }
}
```